# Loading data into UITableview using GCD

Tags: uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

The code below loads data into a UITableView by getting a google news RSS feed parsing the XML and putting it into the view . It works but when i push another view and come back the table view scroll is broken . I have isolated the problem to the GCD code . If i remove it the problem disappears . So here is the GCD code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"View did load ..");
    self.title = @"News stories";

    NewsItem *item = [[NewsItem alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Loading ...";

    self.newsItems = [@[item] mutableCopy];
    NSString *URL = @"http://news.google.com/news?q=apple+OR+google+OR+microsoft&output=rss";
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:xmlURL];
    Parser *parser =  [[Parser alloc] initXMLParser];;

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("news downloader", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        BOOL success;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        if (data != nil) {

            NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

        // create and init our delegate


        // set delegate
            [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

        // parsing...
            success = [nsXmlParser parse];
        }

        else {
            success = FALSE;
        }
        // test the result
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (success) {

                NSLog(@"reloading data ...");
                self.newsItems = [parser.newsItems copy];
                [self.tableView reloadData];

        } else {
                 NewsItem *item = [[NewsItem alloc] init];
                item.title = @"Error loading";

                self.newsItems = [@[item] mutableCopy];
                [self.tableView reloadData];


            NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
        }

        });


    });



}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the scroll is broken"?

Comment: it scrolls only partially .. its hard to describe .. it screws up the table view and it dosent scroll off the edge of the screen if i push another view controller and pop back . if i remove the GCD calls this dosent happen .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: When you leave the table view that has dynamic content, the state you find it in when you come back is undefined. `viewDidAppear` is among other things for this purpose.

Comment: thanks .. you're the man !! didnt know that . where can i read up on this kind of stuff (which apple guide) ?

Comment: [View controller class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) and [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)